# Python PIL: How to save cropped image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, crop

I have a script which creates an image and the it crops it. The problem is that after I call the crop() method it does not save on the disk

```
crop = image.crop(x_offset, Y_offset, width, height).load()
return crop.save(image_path, format)
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an exception? What is ``image_path`` and ``format``?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments to `.crop()` in a tuple. And don't use `.load()`

```
box = (x_offset, Y_offset, width, height)
crop = image.crop(box)
return crop.save(image_path, format)
```

That's all you need. Although, I'm not sure why you're returning the result of the save operation; it returns `None`.

Comment: according to the documentation you need `box = (x_offset, y_offset, x_offset + width, y_offset + height)`

Answer (score 1):

The main trouble is trying to use the object returned by `load()` as an image object. From the PIL documentation:

> In [PIL] 1.1.6 and later, load returns a pixel access object that can be used to read and modify pixels. The access object behaves like a 2-dimensional array [...]

Try this:

```
crop = image.crop((x_offset, Y_offset, width, height))   # note the tuple
crop.load()    # OK but not needed!
return crop.save(image_path, format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working aswer with a NEW version of PIL 1.1.7. The crop coordinates are now **upper left corner** and **lower right corner** (NOT the x, y, width, height).

The version number for python is: 2.7.15

and for PIL: 1.1.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image
import PIL, sys

print sys.version, PIL.VERSION


for fn in ['im000001.png']:

    center_x    = 200
    center_y    = 500

    half_width       = 500
    half_height      = 100

    imageObject = Image.open(fn)

    #cropped = imageObject.crop((200, 100, 400, 300))


    cropped = imageObject.crop((center_x - half_width,
                                center_y - half_height, 
                                center_x + half_width,
                                center_y + half_height,
                                ))

    cropped.save('crop_' + fn, 'PNG')
```

Comment: What's the exact usage of "for fn in ['im000001.png']:" in the actual code execution environment.

Comment: I used this for multiple files and tested it with only one. The list in for line is replaced with glob.glob(''*.PNG")